# unable to add multiple campaigns to single opportunity record from apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created one visualforce which will have campaigns with checkbox for selecting the campaign when multiple campaigns are selected and click on save button then iam unable to add multiple campaigns to one single opportunity under campaign influence related list.

> **Extension:**

```
public with sharing class addCampaign{

    public  List<campaignWrapperClass> cwc{get;set;}
    Opportunity currentRecord;

    public addCampaign(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        currentRecord = new Opportunity();
        List<Campaign> lstCampaign = new List<Campaign> ();
        cwc = new list<campaignWrapperClass>();
        currentRecord = [Select id,practice__c,campaignId from opportunity where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') ];
        lstCampaign = [select id,name from campaign where recordtype.name =: currentRecord.Practice__c ];

        for(campaign cmp1:lstCampaign ){
            cwc .add(new campaignWrapperClass(cmp1) );
        }
    }

    public pageReference addCampaign(){

        List<campaign> lstcmp = new List<campaign>();

        for(campaignWrapperClass cmpWrp :cwc ){
            if(cmpWrp.isSelected == true)
            lstcmp.add(cmpWrp.campName );
        }
        for(campaign c :lstcmp) {
            currentRecord .CampaignId = lstcmp[0].Id;
        }
        update currentRecord ;
        return new pagereference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
    }

    public class campaignWrapperClass{

        public boolean isSelected {get;set;}
        public campaign campName {get;set;}

        public  campaignWrapperClass(campaign cmp){
            isSelected =false;
            campName = cmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? I don't see `System.debug( )` statements in your code that will help you debug your code using [debug logs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm).

Comment: @Mahmood From the above code for(campaign c :lstcmp) {
            currentRecord .CampaignId = lstcmp[0].Id;
        } here i am setting only one campaign to opportunity record i need to set campaigns to the same opportunity is there a way to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
lstcmp[0].Id
```

replace above statement in your code with following code

```
c.Id
```

Your for loop is already iterating through the lstcmp List then we dont need to specify particular element as lstcmp[0]. Instead use c which you have specified a variable to point an element of the lstcmp.

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem**

You are already iterating on Campaings in your second `for` loop, so if you select `lstcmp[0].Id` it will always be pointing to the same Campaign which is residing at location **zero** of your campaign list  `lstcmp`.

> **Solution**

On your code, **replace** the line

```
for(campaign c :lstcmp) {
    currentRecord .CampaignId = lstcmp[0].Id;
}
```

with the **following**

```
for(campaign c :lstcmp) {
   currentRecord.Campaign = c.Id;
}
```

> **Edit**

So, every Campaign you add to a single opportunity, is gonna be part of [CampaignInfluence](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_influence_using.htm&language=en_US&type=0) object and last campaign you add is gonna be the **Primary Campaign Source**.

Comment: If i use the above code then even if iam selecting multiple campaigns it is adding only one campaign to the opportunity

Comment: Every campaign you add is gonna be part of the Opportunity and is gonna fall under CampaignInfluence object. I have updated my answer with necessary details.